# Plotting property surveys using AutoCad MAP2013 - Draw arc problem

Tags: land-survey, autocad-map

This is likely a simple question that I just can't seem to answer.

I am plotting some surveys in AutoCad Map3D but I simply can't figure out how to draw an arc using survey coordinates.

The large majority of my surveys are straight lines which I input as [@distance, bearing] which works fine. How do I use arc coordinates (Arc,Radius,Bearing,Distance) supplied by the surveyor in my plotting?

---

I should mention that I am using shapefiles and creating new polygon features to store my boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arc's are straight forward:

[image]

This can be done interactively or set in the command line following the prompts.

Using AutoCAD 2012 Map 3D here in AutoCAD Classic Mode (not ribbon).

http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2012/ENU/filesACR/WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-5172.htm

For Survey Coordinates follow the guide:
http://www.cadtutor.net/tutorials/autocad/survey-data.php

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using shapefiles and creating new polygon features for my layer to build the boundaries. I don't think this method would work?

Comment: Shapefiles do not support arcs only native dwg/dxf/dng do.

Comment: Hmmm... You can draw Arc's in ArcMap for shapefiles though can't you? So there is no way to draw a curved line using shapefiles in AutoCad?

Comment: see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000000w000000

Answer (score 0):

My CAD is a little rusty and I don't have it installed to test, but the method I used to use is similar to what Mapperz linked to.  I do remember doing it without ever leaving the polyline command (ie drawing the chord bearing as a line then using its endpoints to draw the arc as a separate command).  It's possible this method is no longer valid, and I've been using ArcGIS a lot lately to do this so my CAD memory may be confused (hence I won't type out specific steps).

I do not know what impact working in a shape file would have, but drawing and storing are two different things. In ArcGIS you can draw a curve in a shapefile using the tools, but when you finish sketch it gets converted to straight segments as Mapperz points out.

You might also look at the COGOEDITOR or Traverse tools.  I found a [AutoDesk forum post](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-Civil-3D-General/Entering-bearings-distances-and-curves/td-p/4336693) on the subject, though it doesn't address 'in a shapefile'. There were also several promising sections of the AutoCAD help file, but without that version of the software available I am unable to test.